# Can you run .Formula in C# Interop.Excel without a Range object?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm working with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`
I want to pull the result of running a formula into my code.

I am doing: running the formula, saving the result in a cell, pulling it into a variable, clearing the cell, returning the result as:

```
 ...
 rangeObject = sheetObject.Range["myRange"];
 rangeObject.Formula ="myFormula";     
 string value = rangeObject.Value.ToString();
 sheetObject.Range["myRange"].Clear();
 return value;
 ...
```

Can `rangeObject.Formula ="myFormula";` be run without the `rangeObject`?

Is there a direct approach?

PS: Can the clipboard be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx), the `Evaluate` method of the `Excel.Application` object (which should be available in Interop) can be used to directly evaluate formulas in Microsoft Excel.

Example:

```
// Cells A1 and B1 of the current worksheet contain 3 and 5, respectively.

var myResult = myExcelApp.Evaluate("A1 + B1"); // Yields 8.
```

Comment: I did `string value = applicationObject.Evaluate("myFormula").ToString(); return value;` Works! Thanks.